# call a function when tapping on mask outside a floating component

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm working on a Sencha touch app. Inside a listener, I set up a panel with hideOnMaskTap set to true (based on code from the [floating components documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/floating_components)):

```
onTap: function() {

    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        modal: true,
        hideOnMaskTap: true,
        ...
}
```

This works as expected. Apart from hiding the panel, I would like to call a function when the user taps on the mask. After looking at the sencha documentation and having googled many things, I haven't been able to find a way to make such a call.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When modal:true and hideOnMaskTap:true, once you click on the mask, the component will be hidden. This will fire the hide event.

```
hide( Ext.Component this, Object eOpts )
Fires whenever the Component is hidden
```

Write your code in the handler for this event.

Comment: how is this used? please elaborate.